# Como renderizar o conteúdo de um array

Tags: php, twig, lógica

Na aplicação, exite um menu que está representado no PHP sobre a forma de um array:

```
$menu = [
    ["title" => "Home", "path" => "/home", "children" => []],
    ["title" => "Secção", "path" => "/seccao", "children" => [
        ["title" => "Secção 1", "path" => "/seccao/1", "children" => []],
        ["title" => "Secção 2", "path" => "/seccao/2", "children" => [
             ["title" => "Subsecção 2.1", "path" => "/seccao/2/1", "children" => [
                 ["title" => "Subsecção 2.1.1", "path" => "/seccao/2/1/1", "children" => [
                      ["title" => "Subsecção 2.1.1.1", "/seccao/2/1/1/1", "children" => []],
                      ["title" => "Subsecção 2.1.1.2", "/seccao/2/1/1/2", "children" => []],
                      //...
                 ]],
             ]],
        ]],
    ]],
]
```

O menu acima renderizado deve ficar da seguinte forma:

> - Home
> - Secção
>     -- Secção 1
>     -- Secção 2
>     ---- Subsecção 2.1
>     ------ Subsecção 2.1.1
>     -------- Subsecção 2.1.1.1
>     -------- Subsecção 2.1.1.N

Repare que no exemplo cada posição existente pode ter um número não definido de filhos.

A minha questão é, como renderizar o menu da forma como está no exemplo acima utilizando o twig?

Comment: Recursividade é a chave.

Comment: @DiegoF Esqueci-me de dizer que era utilizando o twig, mas a solução deve ser recursividade na mesma.

Comment: Nesse caso, prefiro sempre um OOP. Essa `array` me lembra o Luciano Hulk ... "Loucura, Loucura, Loucura"

Comment: @WallaceMaxters não entendi. Como OOP pode resolver o problema? Na verdade isso é o resultado que é passado para o twig e não o código em si. Cada posição do array é uma instância do objeto "menu", só que para facilitar eu apenas coloquei um array com strings no exemplo, mas a ideia é a mesma.